# Is there a way to make a C# custom attribute raise a message at compile time?

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes, compile-time

A colleague of mine is using `ObsoleteAttribute` on not-yet-implemented methods so we get the warning at compile time.

Since a method to be implemented is in the exact opposite place of an obsolete one, however, that bugs me.

I don't see a `NotYetImplementedButPleaseBePatientWeVeGotLoadsOfOtherThingsToDoAsWellAttribute` in the documentation, so I'm figuring maybe we could create one.

`ObsoleteAttribute` is `sealed`, so we can't inherit it. (Yes, I found that out when I tried it. Nice try, me.)

Is there another way to imitate `ObsoleteAttribute`, but with a more appropriate name?

Comment: You could write your own analyzer, which uses any attribute you like

Comment: No. The C# compiler itself is the one with some code to spot that attribute and issue a warning

Comment: if it's just about code being semantically "cleaner", one dirty hack would be `using NotYetImplementedAttribute = System.ObsoleteAttribute` - though i'd prefer a `[Obsolete("not yet implemented")]` over that. the compiler warning would, however, be the same.

Comment: I would suggest that your colleague doesn't commit/check in incomplete code.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : good answer. I guess Marc Gravell gave a more thorough one; thanks nonetheless!

Comment: @canton7: theoretically I could, but I have too much work elsewhere for that.

Comment: Yeah, it's important to realise that attributes, in and of themselves, are *passive*. None of their code is invoked at compile time nor even at runtime until *something that knows about them* goes looking for them (and if necessary invokes said code).

Comment: @FranzGleichmann : thanks for the idea (I hadn't thought of it, but as you say it's dirty, so I don't want to clean one end while dirtying another. Even more so as it has no effect on the messages themselves.

Comment: @phuzi: after spending a good part of the last three days reviewing thousands of lines of code, incomplete code almost sounds like a good idea right now. More seriously, while you're right on principle, that's one of the areas where I'm willing to compromise between perfect code quality and time constraints for the coder.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: a very interesting clarification. Thanks again! (Also, for some reason, that part in italics brings up the image of a huge drab gray creature storming through tunnels looking for something Coders Were Not Meant To Know.)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot achieve *exactly* the same as `[Obsolete]`, because that is handled directly by the compiler. However, you could write a "Roslyn analyzer" that looks for *anything you like*, and adds warnings, errors, suggestions, etc, based on your preferences. It could perhaps *even* (perhaps additionally) try to look for `throw new NotImplementedException();`. Writing a Roslyn analyzer is not, however, a trivial task.

Comment: I guess we'll have to go with `ObsoleteAttribute` for now, then. I love a good challenge, but I'll take your word for it and assume that writing a Roslyn analyzer is, if possibly not above my skill, more time-consuming than I can afford at the moment.